# Non-deterministic behavior of npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

After running `npm install`, I have noticed that sometimes `package-lock.json` changes.

This section:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "websocket": {
      "version": "git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git#6c72925e3f8aaaea8dc8450f97627e85263999f2",
      "from": "git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git#6c72925e3f8aaaea8dc8450f97627e85263999f2",
      "requires": {
        "debug": "^2.2.0",
        "nan": "^2.3.3",
        "typedarray-to-buffer": "^3.1.2",
        "yaeti": "^0.0.6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Changes to this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "websocket": {
      "version": "git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git#6c72925e3f8aaaea8dc8450f97627e85263999f2",
      "from": "git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git#6c72925e3f8aaaea8dc8450f97627e85263999f2",
      "requires": {
        "debug": "^2.2.0",
        "nan": "^2.3.3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when that happens, I get a runtime error:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typedarray-to-buffer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\node_modules\websocket\lib\W3CWebSocket.js:18:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

After some debugging, this error is for `require("web3")` in my code.

Here is the relevant section in my `package.json` file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.0.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^7.0.0",
    "decimal.js": "^10.0.0",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.34",
    "ethereumjs-testrpc-sc": "6.1.2",
    "ganache-cli": "6.1.0",
    "solidity-coverage": "0.4.14",
    "truffle": "4.1.3"
  }
```

How can I resolve this, and why does `npm` work differently from time to time?

Comment: Are you able to consistently reproduce this?  Did this happen after you installed a particular package?  Neither of those missing packages are [`deduped`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe).  In the short term, you could explicitly depend on those packages in your own project.  What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same issue stable when deploying code to heroku.

Comment: @AlexG.P.: If I'm not mistaken, go into your `package-lock.json` file, and replace `git:` with `https:`.

Comment: Related https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1914