# Testing via npm command line

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two types of test suites - normal and coverage.

At present, I am allowing one of them via `npm test` and one of them via `npm start`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node scripts/run-truffle-tests.js",
    "start": "node scripts/run-sol-coverage.js"
  }
```

I have a feeling that `npm start` was not originally designated for this purpose.

Is there a better way to implement this?

I was thinking of passing an argument to `npm test`, but I'm not sure that `npm` would pass it on to the script which it is set to invoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add more `scripts`.

I usually have the `tests` for actual, full, single run unit tests to work with CI and other scripts for variations:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node scripts/run-truffle-tests.js && npm run test:coverage",
    "test:continuous": "karma start some.config --run-continuous",
    "test:coverage": "node scripts/run-sol-coverage.js"
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

You can also chain commands with `&&` which will cause the script to be run in sequence and the "total" error code will propagate.  In other words, using the `test` I have above, will run both the unit test and the coverage test.  If either of them return a non-zero exit code, npm will consider the whole test process to have failed.

---

Bear in mind that for custom scripts not named exactly `start` and `test` as well as the other designated scripts found in the docs here: [npm#scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), must be run with

```
npm run scriptname
```

instead of just

```
npm scriptname
```

So in my above example, you would test coverage with:

```
npm run test:coverage
```

Also, the `:` is just a convention.  As far as I know it's not special.

---

Additionally, you **can**

> pass [argument] on to the script which it is set to invoke

Whenever use use `npm test`, what is basically happening is that `npm` runs whatever String value is set in the `package.json`'s `scripts.test` as a process, as though you had typed that String into the shell yourself.  It then looks at the return code and if it's 0, it reports as everything being ok; if it's non-zero, it prints an error.

Comment: The `:` is just a convention... But I still must use `test` as a prefix, right? Because when I tried using anything other than what's specified in the `npm` documentation, I got an error.

Comment: @goodvibration That should not be the case.  What is the name of the script property you are using, what command did you run, and what error did you get?  Put that information as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Well, I used, for example `"coverage": "node scripts/run-sol-coverage.js"`, and then tried to run it via `npm coverage`. Are you saying that I was wrong only in not using `npm run coverage`?

Comment: @goodvibration See the last code snippet of my answer.  The command wouldn't be `npm coverage`, it would be `npm run coverage` with the subcommand `run`.  Npm will only consider certain scripts to be sub commands automatically.

Comment: Any chance you could also take a look at [this npm question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50759779/7400903) of mine?